# Issue in bind parameter 'StorageContext'

Tags: powershell, azure

I am facing the problem when AzureStorageContext retrieved using New-AzureStorageContext command is incompatible with New-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtensionConfig input parameters.

```
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $storage_AccountName –StorageAccountKey $storage_Key

$config2 = New-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtensionConfig -StorageContext $storageContext -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $configuration_FilePath_EventHubListener -role $workerRole_WorkerRoleName
```

> Error: New-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtensionConfig : Cannot bind
>   parameter 'StorageContext'. Cannot convert the 
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of
>   type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" to
>   type 
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext".
>   At
>   C:\Build\BuildScripts\AzurePowershell_V1.3.8-DeployeAndDiagnostics\DeployeAndDiagnosticsNewPowershell.ps1:90
>   char:71
>   + $config2 = New-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtensionConfig -StorageContext $storageCo ...
>   +                                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzureServic...ExtensionConfig], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Extensions.NewAzureServiceDiagnosticsEx
>   tensionConfigCommand

It is working in local but not in the Virtual machine.

Comment: If you can, please paste the solution into an answer and accept it. It's totally OK to answer your own questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is version incompatibility in Azure.Storage.
The version of Azure Powershell module is 4.0.1 in the VM, in my local it 3.4.0. I have uninstalled and installed 3.4.0 in VM from the link given below and it worked well.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure/3.4.0

Comment: According this github issue the Azure Powershell module 4.0.1 (May 15 2017) is indeed incompatible with Azure.Storage 3.0.1. There the suggested solution is to remove it and install **Azure 3.8.0** (April 5th 2017) which has Azure.Storage 2.8.0 as dependency.   `Uninstall-Module -Name Azure.Storage; Uninstall-Module -Name Azure; Install-Module -Name Azure -RequiredVersion 3.8.0`   [https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3976](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3976)